# Determine if one of the keys in multiple arrays sharing the same key structure is the same?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is an example array, which will be used to form another array:

```
$array = [
    ['name' => 'POST', 'value' => 'lorem ipsum 1'],
    ['name' => 'POST', 'value' => 'lorem ipsum 2'],
    ['name' => 'NOT_POST', 'value' => 'lorem ipsum 3'],
]
```

So now, the resulting array will be created based on this the array above, like so:

```
$resultingArray = [
    'POST' => [
        ['value' => 'lorem ipsum 1'],
        ['value' => 'lorem ipsum 2'],
    ],
    'NOT_POST' => ['value => 'lorem ipsum 3']
]
```

My issue is, when I start a `for` loop for `$resultingAraray`, I can't figure out a way to see the keys of the upcoming iterations in order to create the `POST` key which will then be populated with multiple more array of the same key, without having the key repeated (as PHP would pick out the last POST key).

**So my question is:** How do I determine that there are multiple same `name` keys on different arrays, before I start adding to the `$resultingArray` array?

Obviously my array's a little more complex, but the `name` key is shared between all of them, just like in the example.

Comment: Use `foreach` then.

Comment: I can't see how that would make a difference. Care to explain? @u_mulder

Comment: Why no consistency? Your `post` is multidimensional while the `NOT_POST` is not

Comment: You don't need to foresee the future keys, all you need is to check if that key was already created or not in your new array, to add to it instead of creating a new array

Comment: @Kaddath I wont need to go multidimensional if the key is repeated, only when there are multiple of the same `name` (which I need to determine somehow, hence this question), then I create an array which I add to. How do I determine that there are multiple same `name` keys on different arrays?

Comment: that's the same methodology. Don't try to foresee what's coming, test what was created instead. All you have to do is to be careful to remember that what was the `name` is now something else (the main key, now). If your `name` exists in your main keys, your main array key value must become an array with its existing value inside, before adding the new row

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `for` use `foreach`:

```
foreach ($resultingArray as $key => $value) {
    echo 'Under key ' . $key . ' you have: '; 
    print_r($value);
}
```

If you question is how to **create** a `$resultingArray` then you should state it **more clear**.

```
$resultingArray = [];
foreach ($array as $item) {
    if (empty($resultingArray[$item['name']])) {
        $resultingArray[$item['name']] = [];
    }

    $resultingArray[$item['name']][] = ['value' => $item['value']];
}
```

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, but `$resultingArray` doesn't exist, it should derive from `$array`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a foreach to loop over the `$array`, store the `name` key, check if the key exists on the `$resultingArray`. If not, add the current array into it, else, add a level an push the new one.

```
$array = [
    ['name' => 'POST', 'value' => 'lorem ipsum 1'],
    ['name' => 'POST', 'value' => 'lorem ipsum 2'],
    ['name' => 'NOT_POST', 'value' => 'lorem ipsum 3'],
];

$resultingArray = [];
foreach ($array as $item) {
    // get the name
    $name = $item['name'] ;
    // remove name from array
    unset($item['name']);
    // if already exists,
    if (isset($resultingArray[$name])) {
        // transform as array
        $resultingArray[$name] = [$resultingArray[$name]];
        // and push the new one
        $resultingArray[$name][] = $item ;
    } else {
        // store 'as value'
        $resultingArray[$name] = $item;
    }
}
print_r($resultingArray);
```

Will outputs:

```
Array
(
    [POST] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [value] => lorem ipsum 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [value] => lorem ipsum 2
                )

        )

    [NOT_POST] => Array
        (
            [value] => lorem ipsum 3
        )

)
```